# Regex replace phone numbers with asterisks pattern

Tags: regex

I want to apply a mask to my phone numbers replacing some characters with "*".

The specification is the next:

**Phone entry**: (123) 123-1234

**Output**: (1**) ***-**34

I was trying with this pattern: `"\B\d(?=(?:\D*\d){2})"` and the replacing the matches with a "*"

But the final input is something like `(123)465-7891 -> (1**)4**-7*91`

Pretty similar than I want but with two extra matches. I was thinking to find a way to use the match zero or once option (??) but not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?<!\()\d(?!\d?$)
```

Replace each match with `*`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ai3wdD/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\()` - negative lookbehind to find the position which is not immediately preceded by `(`
- `\d` - matches a digit
- `(?!$)` - negative lookahead to find the position not immediately followed by an optional digit followed by end of the line

Answer (score 3):

Alternative without lookarounds :

- match `\((\d)\d{2}\)\s+\d{3}-\d{2}(\d{2})`
- replace by `(\1**) ***-**\2`

In my opinion you should avoid lookarounds when possible. I find them less readable, they are less portable and often less performant.

Testing Gurman's regex and mine on regex101's php engine, [mine completes in 14 steps](https://regex101.com/r/4s6OZ4/1/) while [Gurman's completes in 80 steps](https://regex101.com/r/liRLaG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Some "quickie":

```
function maskNumber(number){
    var getNumLength = number.length;
    // The number of asterisk, when added to 4 should correspond to length of the number
    var asteriskLength = getNumLength - 4;
    var maskNumber = number.substr(-4); 
    for (var i = 0; i < asteriskLength; i++) maskNumber+= '*';

    var mask = maskNumber.split(''), maskLength = mask.length;
    for(var i = maskLength - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = mask[i];
        mask[i] = mask[j];
        mask[j] = tmp;
    }

    return mask.join('');
}
```