# Ignore 2 first characters and select 6 characters of a number and replace to asterisk * with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to hide/replace with * the 6 middle characters of a number, but I'm not getting the desired result.

Input:

```
54998524154
```

Expected output:

```
54*****154
```

What I tried:

```
 const phone = "54998524154"
 phone.replace(/(?<=^[0-9]{2})([0-9]{6})/g, '*')
```

It returns

```
 54*154
```

I also tried replaceAll, but it returns the same result.

Edit: I'd like to achieve it using only one * like:

[Replace phone numbers with asterisks pattern by Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516973/replace-phone-numbers-with-asterisks-pattern-by-regex)

[Regex replace phone numbers with asterisks pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707528/regex-replace-phone-numbers-with-asterisks-pattern)

Comment: you are replacing all 6 digits with ONE asterisk `*`. Use 6 asterisk `******` if 6 is static

Comment: I'd like to do something like this https://regex101.com/r/Ai3wdD/2 . It replaces without 6 *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind? It matches the 3rd through 8th digit successively, replacing each single digit with a single asterisk.

```
/(?<=^\d{2,7}?)\d/g
```

It takes advantage of Javascript's ability to specify variable length lookbehinds.

Here it is on Regex101, with your single example:
[image]

**EDIT**
Based on OP's comments, it seems like there may be punctuation between the digits that should be preserved. This approach can be easily extended to ignore non-digits (\D in regex) by adding an optional number of them before and after each digit.  Like this:

```
(?<=^\D*(\d\D*){2,7}?)\d
```

This will turn `(123) 456-7890` into `(12*) ***-**90`, preserving all punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the below regex.

```js
console.log("54998524154".replace(/(\d{2})\d{6}/,"$1******"))
```

In fact, you can do it without regex as well.

```js
var numStr = '54998524154';
console.log(numStr.replace(numStr.substring(2,8), "******"));
```

Comment: Actually, I want to do something like this `"4151651651".replaceAll("1","X")
"4X5X65X65X" ` So I guess I need to match each character after first 2 numbers

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707528/regex-replace-phone-numbers-with-asterisks-pattern

Comment: I tried to help with you with your original question. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the input is always going to be 11 chars/digits, you could do something like

```
phone.replace(/(^\d{2})(\d{6})(\d{3}$)/g, "$1******$3");
```

Explanation:
3 capture groups:

1. `(^\d{2})` - from the beginning of the string, select 2 digits
2. `(\d{6})`  - then select 6 digits
3. `(\d{3}$)` - Select last 3 digits

Replace pattern:
`"$1******$3"` - First capture-group, then 6 asterisks, then 3rd capture-group.

Answer (score 1):

Without lookarounds, you might also using split check if the characters are digits and then change single digits to `*` between 2 and 9 characters:

```js
const toAsterix = s => {
  let cnt = 0;
  return s.split('').map(v => {
    const isDigit = /^[0-9]$/.test(v);
    if (isDigit) cnt++;
    return cnt > 2 && cnt < 9 && isDigit ? "*" : v
  }).join('');
}

[
  "54998524154",
  "(123) 456-7890"
].forEach(s => console.log(toAsterix(s)))
```